# Look up table - find y when x=some_value in matlab

Tags: matlab, dictionary, find

I have created a table which contains a matrix of 2 rows and 301 columns. I called it `FD_table.mat`

I want to find the value of y, when x is close to lets say 5.5889 with an epsilon value of 0.001

So far I have this:

```
load FD_table.mat 

find( (x <5.5889+0.001) && (x > 5.5889-0.001) )
```

output : Operands to the `||` and `&&` operators must be convertible to logical scalar
values.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try `&` instead of `&&`?

Comment: && to & worked. now it outputs more than one value that meets the certain criteria above. Need to figure out how to select the first closest y?

Comment: `find(....,1,'first')`